# I can't connect with my git repository, Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I have a problem with my git repository. When i try push, pull, clone etc. i have error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My team leader change key, then I delete old key from my computer:

```
ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.0.33
```

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but I also update my system with Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. After update system, git not works :(

I also, generate new public key and save them to my GitLab account. I am sure that it works and have a correct access rights, because I use this account in my daily work.

I try my public key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And it's the same like GitLab account. I have no idea, please Guys help me, because i don't work remote.

Thanks!

Comment: Which is the result of your git remote -v?

Comment: @juliansalas git remote -v: 
`origin git@git.(...)-frontend.git (fetch)
origin git@git.(...)-frontend.git (push)
`

Comment: `ssh -T git@git.(...)-frontend.git ` should tell you more.

Comment: @Jakuje `ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.(..)frontend.git: Name or service not known` after ssh -T git@git

Comment: Then you have either typo in the server name or problem with the DNS

Comment: @Jakuje when i try `ssh -T git@git.DOMAIN.pl` then back `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Ok, thanks for help me! I try search about this problem and I resolve them!

After updating my system change access to "workspace" folder. I resolve my problem, one command: 

    `sudo chown -R youruser:yourgroup myWorkspaceFolder`

Thanks Guys!